# knockout js variable override

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have some global variables in my script:

```
var yardsToFirst = 10;
var yardsToTD = 80;
var exactDown = 1;
```

In my ViewModel I take in and modify the variables. According to Google Chrome's javascript  console the variables are being modified. I try to have them observed so they can update the UI like this:

```
self.down = ko.observable(exactDown);
self.toGo = ko.observable(yardsToFirst);
self.toGoal = ko.observable(yardsToTD);
```

It all works fine right when I load the page. The problem comes when I start modifying the data. the UI never changes. I have checked and the javascript console says the global variables hold the correct numbers but still the UI is not updated. Am I doing something that is impossible or have I go about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. When you create knockout observable properties, they will just initialize with the value you gave them, i.e. `ko.observable(exactDown)`. After that, there's no way for knockout to know when the variable you used for initialization changed. It's just like you tried to call `ko.observable(1)`.

Initializing knockout observable property with some global variable doesn't mean that knockout will start to watch that variable for changes.

Instead of modifying global variables like you do:

```
exactDown = newValue;
```

...and expecting that knockout will pick up the new value, you need to modify knockout properties directly, like this:

```
viewModel.down(newValue);
```

To modify knockout properties, you need to call them as functions (since they are basically JavaScript functions).

Comment: Thanks that gives me somewhere to start. I figured I was doing something wrong. thanks again for the input

Comment: That actually gave me enough to figure it out thank you so much